# Getting error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined' on browser refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my portfolio project, when clicked on project image it redirects to a new page giving details of that particular project which works without any flaw, but, when browser is refreshed, it gives error as mentioned above in title. What may be the cause?

Project.js (Here Project Card is created)

```
{  
        data2.map((data, index) => {
          return <MDBCol key={index}>
          <MDBCard style={{ width: "20rem"}}>
          <Link to={{ pathname: `/details/${data.id}`, data:data }}>
          <MDBCardImage className="img-fluid" src={data.img}/>
          </Link>
          </MDBCard>
          <br/>
          </MDBCol>
        })
      }
```

Details.js (When clicked on project image redirects to this page)

```
export default class Details extends Component {
    render() {
        const { data } = this.props.location;
        return (
            <Layout fixedHeader>
            <div className="details-body" key={data.id}>
                <h2 className="details-title">{data.title}</h2>
                <img src={data.img}/>
            </div>         
            </Layout>      
        )
    }
}
```

The error it gives is as below. What possible changes could be made?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution to keep maintaining your data on refreshing page.

Details.js

```
 export default class Details extends Component {
  state = {
    data: this.props.location.data ? this.props.location.data:JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('object'))
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    if(this.props.location.data!==undefined)
    localStorage.setItem("object", JSON.stringify(this.props.location.data));
  }
  render() {
    const {data} =this.state;
    let title = data ? data.title : "";
    let img = data ? data.img : "";
    let id = data ? data.id :0;
    return (
      <Layout fixedHeader>
        <div className="details-body" key={id}>
           <h2 className="details-title">{title}</h2>
           <img src={img} alt="detail-img" />
        </div>         
    </Layout> 
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for helping... Actually I was thinking the same way, as the last solution was none other than localStorage... Well my project finally completed with this line of code... Thanks very much!!!!

Comment: If you don't mind can I ask you 2 more doubts?... Not now later I would push it on codesandbox...

Comment: Those doubts are pertaining to their respective projects, one related to localStorage and other CSS issue

Comment: @Pranav yeah, tell

Comment: Hello   @Vahid Akhtar

Comment: Following is my sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/tdgwm, My question is when clicked on cart button, 'In cart' is displayed which changes from cart icon. Its fine till there, but when refreshed it returns back to cart icon. I've tried with localStorage but, no effect. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you are sending a `data` object using `Link` but when the browser is refreshed that `data` object is not there anymore since `Link` is not responsible for providing it with one.

either put all your required data in the url or store it inside localStorage

Answer (score 0):

In your details page add this code

```
     Export default class Details extends Component {
     render() {
         const { data } = this.props.location;
         return (
            {data && 
             <Layout fixedHeader>
             <div className="details-body" key={data.id}>
                 <h2 className="details-title">{data.title}</h2>
                 <img src={data.img}/>
             </div>         
             </Layout> 
                   }     
               )
              }
            }
```

Comment: so after refresh it wont render because having a check for data if data is there only it will render else nothing will get render

Answer (score 0):

When you refresh the pushed data wont be there.

**First Way**

So either you can add all the required details in the url, like how search in redbus works you will be able to see since the params is in the url it will be easy to refresh.

**Second Way**

So either you can put details in the url if data is more, putting in url is not good, else you can check whether data is there in the component, if its not there with the id you can fetch the data.

**Third Way**

Since you are using react router,  you can do this.props.history.push and add the state .

```
this.props.history.push({
          pathname : '/Taskactive',
          state :{
          role_id : responseJson.userFormat,
          userName : this.userName,
          userid: this.refs.usrname.value
          }
          } 
        );
```

and in the component you can fetch like this

```
this.props.location.state.role_id
```

Either you can pass all the data or the required data like id and  get all required data. 
The above approach data will be there even though after refresh, and you need to clean up when it unmounts

I hope you got a clear view on the problem

Answer (score 0):

this because you send the data with Link but when you refresh the data will go the  way I get around this is to make Link direct me to something like `projects/${id}` then I get my data in the detail page